# Unable to find connect to node.js running on Red Hat server

Tags: node.js, linux, redhat

I have a Red Hat server where my node.js app resides. By default the app is either suppose to run on a port which the user has setup OR on 8080

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    winston.log('info', 'The server has started');
});
```

When I login into the Red Hat server via ssh > go to the node app directory and run

```
node app.js
```

I get

> info: The server has started

So the application is running properly. However when I go to the application url

server_ip_address:8080 (example - 104.37.188.221:8080) it doesn't connect and the connection eventually times out.

I have not setup any environment variable for port so the port will be 8080. I assume if any other service is running on that port it wont let the app run but thats not the case.

Any idea what is going on? How do I debug this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should print listening port in log that will help you debug

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    winston.log('info', 'The server has started on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

and also make sure, you have open port if firewall enabled

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

**Update:**

You may like to add error handler at the end of all routes, something like

```
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({ error: err});
});
```

Comment: So its running on 8080 but the timeout issue is still happening. getting the following error: -jailshell: firewall-cmd: command not found when I run the first firewall command. but i dont think so there is any firewall

Comment: Are you using `ExpressJS` ? Have you handle error(404, 500, etc.)?

Comment: Yes its a node express apllication